Issue Cloning Repository After SSH Key Change
I recently changed my GitHub SSH key and updated it in my GitHub account. Most of my private repositories are working fine, but I’m having trouble cloning a specific repository that I’ve contributed to, but don’t own. I get an error message when trying to clone it.
Here’s what I’ve tried:

Verified that my new SSH key is correctly added to my GitHub account.

Confirmed that I have the necessary permissions for the repository.

Tried to access the repository using HTTPS, and it works fine.


The error message I’m receiving is:
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this?
Thanks in advance for your help!

If you're running the basic Git CLI, and not a GUI client or an IDE with a Git integration, then you should be able to do GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git clone git@github.com:owner/repo (with the correct owner/repo values, of course) and get a verbose output. That should indicate where the problem is.
